# why 2 is automatically converted to 299?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm new:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my calculator");
            Console.WriteLine("Calculator only supports -,+,/,*");
            Console.WriteLine("Calculator V1.20 alpha");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number");
            int num1 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your operator");
            Console.WriteLine();
            char operation = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your second number");
            Console.WriteLine();
            int num2 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            //the answer variables
            int answersubtract = num1 - num2;
            int answeradd = num1 + num2;
            int answermulti = num1 * num2;
            int answerdiv = num1 / num2;


            if (operation == '-')
            {
                Console.WriteLine(answersubtract);
            }

            else if (operation == '+')
            {
                Console.WriteLine(answeradd);
            }
            else
            {
                if (operation == '*')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(answermulti);
                }

                else
                {
                    if (operation == '/')
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(answerdiv);

                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

The input I am sending to the program is:

> 1+2

Comment: Can you please tell us what problem you're having? "When I do _a_, _b_ happens, but I wanted _c_"

Comment: Can you perhaps be a bit more specific?  Under what circumstances is a `2` being converted to a `299`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 int num1 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

You are reading a character, not a number.  Review the docs for ConsoleKeyInfo.KeyChar.

Allow the user to enter real numbers:

```
 int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Focus on error handling and the *switch* statement in version 2 of your program.

Comment: @John - I'm not going to touch that with a ten foot pole.  It isn't relevant anyway.

Comment: Where does 299 come into play (not 229)?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you enter `2` its represented as a `char` which its value is `229`.

Comment: Except the ASCII value of `'2'` is `0x32` or decimal 50.

Comment: @John: This answer does identify a legitimate problem, I don't think it deserves a downvote.

Comment: @John: Using the integral value of the encoding instead of the number it represents is a legitimate problem with the code that should be fixed.  The incorrect value then is going through some computations to arrive at 229, it isn't a single character that has that value, but this problem is almost certainly leading to the incorrect result.

Comment: @John: How am I missing the point?  I'm the one who first pointed out what the ASCII value of `'2'` is.

Comment: @John: None of the answers have explained that.  My best guess is that it's appearing in one of the answer variables, but since 229 is prime, the only one that could get there is 50 + 179, and I don't see how a character 179 would get entered either.

Comment: @John, Ben: The question is missing repro steps.  We have no idea which code path it is following to get that result.  Plus, there's some serious telephone-game going on here, cause the title says `299`, not `229`

Comment: @Merlyn: Good point.  299 is 13*23, and it's entirely feasible for 13 to show up (the `\r` character).  23 is more difficult though.

Comment: Removed all of my "229" comments.

Comment: @Ben, John: Since this is a fun game, I'll throw something in.  The char is 16 bits, so I don't think (?) this could be a multiplication wrapping around.   It could be a subtraction, though I don't think the numbers are big enough.  Also, the numpad has different character codes from the top of the keyboard in both the `ConsoleKeys` and `Keys` enums.

Comment: @Merlyn: Yeah, except he's fetching the `ConsoleKeyInfo.KeyChar` property, not the `ConsoleKeyInfo.Key` property.  Quite a mystery.

Comment: @Ben: Compiled it and found out it is much simpler than that.  The characters he's typing are: "1+2".  The last line takes the `2` he typed and appends `99` to it, hence `299`.

Comment: @Merlyn: could you add your detective work as an answer, please? Maybe with a simplified version of the problem?